# @PathParam is null in Atmopshere

Tags: javascript, java, spring, atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I am trying to implement multi room chat through atmosphere. For this I created a ManagedService with path ="apis/chat/{email}". In the code, i try to set the path param like

```
@PathParam("email")
private String email;
```

My issue is that the value of the email is always NULL, even though the request URI has the email value in the URI.

My Java class AtmosphereChat

```
@ManagedService(path = "apis/chat/{email}", atmosphereConfig = MAX_INACTIVE    + "=120000")
public class AtmosphereChat {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AtmosphereChat.class);

  @Autowired
  private AtmosphereUUID uuid;

  @PathParam("email")
  private String email;
}
```

Web.xml

```
<!-- Chat Servlet using Atmosphere -->
<servlet>
    <description>ChatServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>ChatServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.supporton.blackcarbon.web.chat</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param> 
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.objectFactory</param-name> 
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.spring.SpringWebObjectFactory</param-value> 
    </init-param>  
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.messageContentType</param-name>
        <param-value>application/json</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor.clientHeartbeatFrequencyInSeconds</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.shareableThreadPool</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxProcessingThreads</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcaster.maxAsyncWriteThreads</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterLifeCyclePolicy</param-name>
        <param-value>EMPTY</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ChatServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern><!-- Broadcast default will lookup this -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using Spring 4.2.6 and Atmoshpere 2.4.2. What could be that I am doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you doing something with integration between `Spring` and `Atmosphere`? If yes, this `web.xml` seems to be not right way, anyway, you should try its official demo first.